# Valid SSL Certificate , Local Host

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a web page with apache, and it is hosted only in localhost, but all devices that are connected to my network can be entered using my ipv4 (192.168.1.x), I have installed a certificate using openssl, but the certificate is only valid For my pc where I am hosting the site, if I try to enter with another device it tells me that it is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected since the Certificate Authority (who emitted your certificate) is not trusted by the browsers. You'd need to install your CA certificate in your clients in order to make them trust the certificates emitted by that CA.

If you own a **valid domain**, you may buy a certificate for it from a trusted CA, or even emit a certificate using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), which emits free SSL certificates that are trusted by all major browsers currently. Remember that this won't work neither for invalid/local domains or domains that you don't own.

Comment: I am hosting my page on my PC, so it will only be for people who are connected to the same Wi-Fi, so I tried to use Let's Encrypt but it asks me for an ipv6.

Comment: I'd just ignore the SSL error while you don't publish it using a public/valid domain name. Otherwise, just install the CA certificate in the clients' machines and the error will disappear.